# How to neglect duplicate value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I am having duplicates value also.

From that table, I want to count duplicate value as ***1***.

I am using below query to find count

```
SELECT id, team, count(*) as votes FROM vot GROUP BY team ORDER BY votes DESC;
```

From this query, I get the duplicates count also.

I hope I made my query clear.

I am very new to MySQL.

Comment: Use `COUNT(DISTINCT columnnames)` where `columnnames` is a comma-separated list of the columns whose duplicates should be ignored.

Comment: Use of ```DISTINCT``` keyword. Have a look at these links https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp     https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

What I got from your question is:
Instead of --

```
id team votes
1   A   2
3   C   2
2   B   1
```

you want --

```
id team votes
1   A   1
2   B   1
3   C   1
```

For this result use the following query:

```
SELECT id, team, count(distinct team) as votes FROM vot GROUP BY team,id ORDER BY votes DESC;
```

Comment: @golie . . . `count(distinct)` in this case is superfluous.  You might as well use `1 as votes` because `team` is an aggregation key.